# Getting list of installed programs from QT program on Linux

Tags: linux, qt

I need to get a list of installed programs with the path tho the icon and the executable on Linux from a QTWidget program. I know I have to use QProcess but i'm pretty new on this. Any ideas will be pretty helpfull.

Comment: Linux is too broad of a platform for something like this. If you're willing to narrow it down to just one desktop manager (or package manager) you could start there -- assuming you're even talking about desktop Linux!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it is desktop. I want to create an app launcher I'ven staring projects like GnomePie,Docky etc. But the way you add the program to the launcher is a little bit complicated for a common user so you gotta select icon, and the executable of the program.